# Go to Google Chrome shortcut in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts

I have Windows 8.1. Because of the nature of my work, I have several application windows open at any given point in time. I know that in order to cycle between various application windows, one may use the `Alt + Tab` keyboard shortcut. However, because I have several windows open, it is a rather inconvenient way to simply come back to my Google Chrome window. Is there a way to designate a keyboard shortcut for Google Chrome such that pressing the shortcut brings the Google Chrome Window into focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Chrome pinned to your task bar, you can press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> if it's the first pinned program, <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> if it's the second, etc.